# Vertically centering label with input

Tags: bulma

using the following bulma code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="field is-horizontal">
      <label class="label">test</label>
      <div class="control is-horizontal">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder=""  />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/6jqrzkxj/)

it doesn't vertically center the label with the input.

[image]

is there a bulma modifier to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you need to wrap your label in a field-label

```
<div class="field-label is-normal">
  <label class="label">test</label>
</div>
```